# Java ClassCastException javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart

Tags: java

When am trying to read email from SMTP server on Linux platform it thorw Multipart Class cast exception but it properly work on windows platform. kindly assist me that what is the main issue on Linux platform. thanks

```
Email Content Type : multipart/mixed;

Email Attachment   :  boundary="doBdxOr1WFK/0oBG/sJf8iChfky6UG3OUxjg7g=="

Exception          : javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart

Method Name : getContentFromMultipart
```

```
public class ReadEmail {

private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_HTML = "text/html";
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_CALENDAR = "text/calendar";
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_ALTERNATIVE = "multipart/alternative";
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_RELATED = "multipart/related";
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_MIXED = "multipart/mixed";
private boolean plainTextEmail;
private String contentType;

private String getContent(Message msg) throws Exception {
    String emailContent = "";
    try {
        // if email content contains multiple content types/attachments
        if (msg.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
            emailContent = this.getContentFromMultipart(msg);
        } else if (msg.getContent() instanceof String) {
            // if email content is only text based or html based
            if (msg.getContentType().contains(this.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                plainTextEmail = true;
                contentType = this.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN;
                emailContent += msg.getContent().toString();
            } else if (msg.getContentType().contains(this.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_HTML)) {
                plainTextEmail = false;
                contentType = this.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_HTML;
                emailContent += msg.getContent().toString();
            }

            return emailContent;
        }
        // if email content is in the form of input string (Bain Capital
        // link based emails)
        else if (msg.getContent() instanceof InputStream) {
            logger.log(msg.getContentType());
            if (msg.getContentType().contains(this.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_CALENDAR)) {
                contentType = this.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_CALENDAR;
            }
            if (msg.getContentType().contains("multipart/mixed")) {
                contentType = "multipart/mixed"; // this.CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_MIXED;
                if (msg.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
                    emailContent += emailContent = this.getContentFromMultipart(msg, this);
                }
            }
            InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) msg.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line);
            }
            emailContent = out.toString();

            inputStream.close();
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        emailContent = "exception";
    }
    return emailContent;
}

private String getContentFromMultipart(Message msg) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    Object objectContent = msg.getContent();
    Multipart mp = (Multipart) objectContent;
    int count = mp.getCount();
    String emailContent = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (mp.getBodyPart(i).getContentType().contains(this.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_HTML)) {
            plainTextEmail = false;
            contentType = this.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_HTML;
            emailContent += mp.getBodyPart(i).getContent().toString();
        } else if (mp.getBodyPart(i).getContentType().contains(this.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
            plainTextEmail = true;
            contentType = this.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN;
            emailContent += mp.getBodyPart(i).getContent().toString();
        } else if (mp.getBodyPart(i).getContentType().contains(this.CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_ALTERNATIVE) || mp.getBodyPart(i).getContentType().contains(this.CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_RELATED)
                || mp.getBodyPart(i).getContentType().contains(this.CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_MIXED)) {
            emailContent += parseMultipartEmailContent(mp.getBodyPart(i));
        }
    }
    return emailContent;
}

}
```

Comment: There are 2 overloaded methods for getContentFromMultipart. Which one is throwing error?

Comment: getContentFromMultipart Method is throwing exception in 2nd line weather i called this method in 'multipart' cases

Comment: and there is only one method not two overloaded this.getContentFromMultipart(msg, this) this was by mistake actually it used only one parameter like msg

Comment: i don't think this problem of `ClassCastException `came because of platform change of OS (Window to Linux).

Comment: actually this is the main cause i tested it several times

Comment: @user2803576 I believe this error is coming when "msg.getContent() instanceof InputStream" condition satisfies. Can you please triple check?

Comment: It was resolved, issue trigger due to the classloader problem.